# How do I enable SVN menu in an editor window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

The SVN menu (Subversive Plugin) is disabled whenever I'm in an edit window; it's enabled when I'm in the Navigator or similar file browsing windows. I'd like to have the SVN menu enabled while the editor window is open in order so that I can set up a key binding and commit while editing the document rather than having to switch over to the navigation view to commit a file. This is Eclipse 3.5 using Eclipse's Subversion Connectors plugin.

This may be related: I had to do a reinstall of eclipse and a fair number of the keybindings no longer work the way the once did. In addition, many keystrokes now only work in windows only instead of windows and dialogs (specifically select all, copy, and paste). If these problems are related and there's an easy way to repair or refresh my keybindings without having to start over completely that would be great.

## Clarification

I know how to set up key mappings. That's not a problem. I have them set up. The problem is that the **SVN menu is disabled in the editor pane**. I can access the SVN menu from the Navigator or similar panes, and I've set up the keymappings exactly the way I want them. They just aren't working in all contexts.

## Update

I just switched to Subclipse. That pretty much solved all my problems.

Comment: Which Subversion plugin are you using: Subclipse or Subversive?

Answer (score 0):

well, it sounds like you have an "answer" for your own problems, though you haven't marked this as answered.

in general, can't you go to the toolbar, get the customize menu (right-click or ctrl-click depending upon environment), and choose "customize perspective", then get into the Command Groups Availability tab, turn on what you want there, and then make the menus visible in the other tabs as interested?

would that not bring up the subversive menu for you even in the editor?

Comment: The menu was visible but disabled. So I think it was a different issue.